# Манипулятор C++

Tags: c++, вывод

Нужно написать манипулятор, который будет ограничивать количество символов на число до n, и количество цифр после запятой до n. Как указать сколько цифр нужно после запятой, мне удалось найти и всё прекрасно работает. Но как сделать не более n символов на число мне не удаётся найти, возможно ли вообще это сделать ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using std::ostream;
using std::fixed;
using std::cout;
ostream& manipulator(ostream& s)
{

    s << fixed;
    s.precision(4);
    return s;
}
int main()
{
    double d = 3241213412.123432;
    cout << manipulator << d;
}
```

Данный код ограничивает количество цифр после запятой.

Comment: что значит "не удается найти"? Вам решать нужно, а не находить. И где код, который вам удался написать и который "прекрасно работает"?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Код добавил. Извините конечно, я, наверное, не совсем понимаю, как вы изучаете новые темы по программированию. Когда я изучаю, то просматриваю разные источники. В них я не нашёл метода для потока, который поможет ограничить количество символов на вывод. Поэтому задаюсь вопросом, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых этот манипулятор не правильный:

1. Используется другой(стандартный) манипулятор `std::fixed`, что не
   есть хорошо.
2. Устанавливается конкретная точность (4), и изменить ее нет
   возможности.

Такой манипулятор должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
ostream& setfp(const size_t w)
{
    return //но как?;
}
```

Для этого придется написать класс манипулятора, который хранит указатель на функцию, принимающую и поток и точность, а потом написать эту функцию и оператор вывода манипулятора:

```
using std::ostream;
struct My_manip {
    using F = ostream&(*)(ostream&, const size_t);
    F f;
    const  size_t n;
    My_manip(F func, const size_t width)
        : f(func), n(width) {}
};
//функция выполняющая то, что должен делать манипулятор
ostream& set_w(ostream& os, const size_t w)
{
    os.setf(os.fixed, os.floatfield);
    os.precision(w);
    return os;
}
//а манипулятор хранит функцию и точность
My_manip setfp(const size_t w)
{
    return { set_w, w };
}
//теперь как запустим в поток манипулятор
//вызывая функцию, выполняющую задачу
ostream&
operator<<(ostream& os, const My_manip& m)
{
    return  m.f(os, m.n);
}
//теперь можете передать любую точность
void g(size_t k, double d) { cout << setfp(k) << d; }
```

Чтобы выполнить что то другое, просто нужно написать другую функцию `set_w1` и манипулятор `setp`  вернет`{ set_w1, n}`

По поводу "не более n символов на число" не совсем ясно какое число имеется ввиду(с плавающей точкой или просто вывести ограниченное количество символов?). Проясните, добавлю подсказку.

P.S. Для того, чтобы вывести некоторое ограниченное количество символов, наверное придется написать фасет локализации. Или же написать класс буфера и `заменить буфер std::cout` (в конце обратно восстановить старый).

Но, конкретно, чтобы вывести некоторое количество символов  для числа в поток std::cout, можно изворачиваться манипулятором. Я напишу пример такого манипулятора, а вы потом можете переделать для другого потока или для вывода другого типа(пусть это будет вашим заданием, чтобы лучше понять логику кода).

```
using std::ostream;
//ссылочный тип. Роли: выполнять код при вводе
//возвращать потока ввода
struct stream {
    ostream& os = std::cout;
    const size_t N;
    stream(const size_t w) : N(w){}
    stream& operator<<(int n)
    {
        //количество цифр в числе
        size_t k = static_cast<size_t>(log10(n)) + 1;
        while (k-- > N)
            n /= 10;
        os << n;
        return *this;
    }
};
//манипулятор для ввода в поток
struct My_manip : stream
{    
    My_manip(const size_t w)
        : stream(w) { }       
};
//получение манипулятора
My_manip f(const size_t w)
{
    return My_manip(w);
}
//оператор ввода манипулятора
stream operator <<(ostream& os, const My_manip& m)
{
    return dynamic_cast<const stream&>(m);
}


//пример использования
int main() {     
    const size_t n = 3;
    std::cout << f(n) << 889667;
    std::cout   << "\nit is the first " << n
        << " digits of the number\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь есть недоработки, связанное с тем, что выражение с манипулятором, не возвращает ссылку на cout. В данном случаи это не важно, потому что вряд ли кому понадобится такое. Здесь цель обучающий, где заодно выплывают недостатки порядка не переносимости кода для использования где нибудь еще...

Comment: Ограниченное количество символов. Тип числа не важен, нужно как для числа с плавающей запятой, так и для целого числа.

Comment: а как вообще вывести ограниченное количество символов, вы знаете?

Comment: Я — нет. Поэтому спросил на форуме, возможно ли это вообще

Comment: Техническое задание подразумевает: "3 знака после запятой, не более 7 символов на число".  Знаки после запятой это просто. А вот с символами сложнее. я лично не совсем понимаю, думал есть какой-то метод для потока, позволяющий это.

Comment: @Bol4onok, если число не влезает вы хотите резать старшие или младшие цифры? Поскольку на практике смысла в таких действиях нет, то и стандартный способ не предусмотрен

Comment: С праздником вас.  Добавлено в ответе то, что вы просите..  Разъяснительные комментарии могу дополнить позже(нехватка времени)

Comment: А всё таки, что нужно сделать, чтобы выводить значения другого типа, например `unsigned long`?

Comment: @wololo, код специально не доработан.  Во первых этого добиваться не нужно, во вторых нужно оставлять спортивный интерес, потому что писать такой манипулятор полезно лишь для учебных целей.  Вообще то тут, думаю, уместно было бы использовать патерн "стратегия"  и, конечно, доработать до лучшего и надежного вида(например в реализации функций  задействовать  объект std::ostream::sentry, чтобы выражение вернуло ostream&....). Не думаю, что если логика подхода понятна, трудно доработать и для других интегральных типов.,

Comment: Меня интересует не манипулятор в целом, а только алгоритм усечения целого числа. Как он по вашему будет выглядеть для типа `unsigned long`? Полагаю речь идёт о функции `stream& operator<<(int n)`?

Comment: @wololo,
  stream& operator<<(stream& s, unsigned long n)
    {
        unsigned long id = 1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s.N ; ++i)
            id *= 10;
        while (n > id)
            n /= 10;
        s.os << n;
        return s;
    }

Comment: Избавились от логарифма. Мудрое решение :) Чего же в ответе предлагаете считать через логарифм?

Comment: @wololo,  и так много написал, просто хотелось урезать  количество символов , одним словом из за лени.

Comment: Меня не перестаёт удивлять упорство, с которым функции для работы с плавающей точкой используются в целочисленных задачах. На мой взгляд арифметику с плавающей точкой без особой необходимости привлекать не следует. Вариант с логарифмом для типа `unsigned long` на некоторых входных данных [работает неверно](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80874c2d0e2f9507). Данный способ может [работать неверно и для типа `int`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/794253354676d190). Хотя в этом примере набор опций компилятора, конечно, спорный.